# Angular - $viewValue or $modelValue in validation?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm new to Angular and I want to check I am doing form validation right. I want to display an appropriate message when the user has entered more than 100 characters in an input field.
For this I am using $viewValue. Would $modelValue be better for validation since it is what has been 'saved' in the controller? Is there a better way to do this kind of specific validation?

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Forename" class="control-label col-md-2">Forename</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input id="forename" type="text" class="form-control"
                       name="detailsForename"
                       required
                       ng-maxlength="100"
                       ng-model="vm.customer.Forename" />
            </div>
        </div>



                    <li ng-show="detailsForm.detailsForename.$error.required">
                        Forename must be filled in
                    </li>
                    <li ng-show="!detailsForm.detailsForename.$valid">
                        Forename was not valid
                    </li>
                    <li ng-show="detailsForm.detailsForename.$viewValue.length > 100">
                        Forename must be no more than 100 characters
                    </li>
```

UPDATE: I had tried vm.person.Forename but for whatever reason it was not working. If it *should* work I shall revisit that as a possibility.
Using $valid is not enough because if the input field is empty I will get the error message for Required, and for > 100 (because $valid=false)

Comment: Why not just use "<li ng-show="vm.customer.Forename.length > 100">"?

Comment: you can also use $valid, as shown in the example of https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the [ngMaxlength docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength): "The validator sets the maxlength error key if the ngModel.$viewValue is longer than the integer ..."

So in your case that would be: `detailsForm.detailsForename.$error.maxlength`

You should never need to access an `ngModel's` `$viewValue` or `$modelValue` from the template.

Comment: OH I did not know I could do $error.maxlength (was not in my course). And the extra info that I should not need to access $viewValue etc. is what I was hoping to learn. Thank you.